# How to add navigation bottom bar in activity from fragment

Tags: android

I have already add an bottom navigation bar into my project with 3 fragments (Home_fragment, Wallet_fragment, Account_fragment). I have added login button in Account_fragment. Now I want that Whenever I click on login button login_fragment (afterlogin activity) open with bottom navigation bar.

I have attaching a link to video showing my problem:

https://cloud.degoo.com/share/o41Axz4FYFHBx7

And here is code, starting with mainActivity:

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, new HomeFragment()).commit();

}



BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment selecrFlag = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                selecrFlag = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_wallet:
                selecrFlag = new WalletFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_Account:
                selecrFlag = new AccountFragment();
                break;


        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, selecrFlag).commit();
        return true;


    }


};

};
```

Account_fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    EmailID = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    Passwd = v.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    SignUpBt = v.findViewById(R.id.signbutton);
    LoginBt = v.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

    LoginBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AccountFragment.this.getContext(),AfterLogin.class));
        }
    });
```

afterlogin Fragment:

```
package com.thechamp.earnbyads;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class AfterLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);


    }
}
```

Comment: It's a very bad practice to duplicate the bottom nav in different activities, it just not the purpose. You should make the SignUp Activity into a fragment. so when clicking the button you just replace fragments and that's it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this